# How to add single vertical lines in a table?

Tags: tables

I need to add a single vertical line between the first and the second column (right to eta squared and Means) and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Here's an example of my code. I need the vertical line to be positioned between the horizontal lines but not to "touch them". I would appreciate any tips as to how I could do that. :)
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}           % for placing figures
\usepackage{titlesec}        % for formatting APA-style headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref} % show PDF bookmarks upon opening
\usepackage{bookmark} % produce bookmarks

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{xxx.}
        \label{tab:simresults}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrccc}
            \hline
            & & a & b & c \\
            \hline
            $\eta^2$ & DIF item proportion & \emph{0.52} & \emph{0.13} & \emph{0.00} \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{Mean}&0.20 & 0.91 & 9.83 & 0.00 \\
            &0.60 & 0.71 & 8.44 & 0.00 \\
            &0.80 & 0.51 & 7.40 & -0.01\\
            \hline

            \hline
        \end{tabular}


    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the desired output? Should the line continue in the row with the column headers as well? [Is this what you ant to achieve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s0JD.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @leandriis. Yes, exactly! I'm sorry I didn't add a sketch.

Comment: @Zarko thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a  single vertical line not touching the horizontal rules, use the rules from `booktabs`: they have some vertical padding which interrupts the vertical lines.

Unrelated: needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`. The latter does it for you.

So I propose this layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable, multirow}
\usepackage{float} % for placing figures
\usepackage{titlesec} % for formatting APA-style headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref} % show PDF bookmarks upon opening
\usepackage{bookmark} % produce bookmarks

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Main effects of the simulated conditions on outcome variables.}
        \label{tab:simresults}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l!{\color{Silver!40!Lavender}\vrule width 1.8pt}rccc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & Hit Rate & Cluster Length & Bias in Slope \\
            \midrule
            $\eta^2$ & DIF item proportion & \emph{0.52} & \emph{0.13} & \emph{0.00} \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{Mean}&0.20 & 0.91 & 9.83 & 0.00 \\
            &0.60 & 0.71 & 8.44 & 0.00 \\
            &0.80 & 0.51 & 7.40 &\llap{$-$}0.01\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\small%
            \item \emph{Note.} italics = Eta squared (explained variance proportion). See supplements for higher order effects. * Not all single steps are printed.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you so much! Is there a way to except the first row (where the column names are)?

Comment: You can add a `\multicolumn` command as follows: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& & Hit Rate & Cluster Length & Bias in Slope \\ `

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a million!

Comment: @oopsicusmaximus: as leandriis said. Please see the updated code and image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\I{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{detect-all,
             table-format=-1.2}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Main effects of the simulated conditions on outcome variables.}
        \label{tab:simresults}
        \begin{tabular}{lr|*{3}{S}}
            \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}
        &   {\makecell{Hit\\ Rate}} 
            &   {\makecell{Cluster\\ Length}} 
                &   {\makecell{Bias\\ in Slope}}    \\
\hline
$\eta^2$ & DIF item proportion 
            &\I 0.52    &\I  0.13    &\I 0.00    \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Mean}
    & 0.20  & 0.91      & 9.83      &   0.00    \\
    & 0.60  & 0.71      & 8.44      &   0.00    \\
    & 0.80  & 0.51      & 7.40      &  -0.01    \\
            \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\small
            \note{See supplements for higher order effects.}

            \item[$\eta^2$] explained variance proportion
            \item[*]        not all single steps are printed.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In preamble are considered only packages needed for this table.

Comment: Not quite, but I can definitely use that the next time I'm working with tables. :)

Comment: You should told me, what is not done as you like to have.